# Questions about ActiveSpaceTransformer code implementation

Tags: qiskit, hamiltonian-simulation

1. Could anyone explain how [dipole moment](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-nature/blob/5166687c7a76c512ce560ecbe847abdce0d45d02/qiskit_nature/second_q/transformers/active_space_transformer.py#L602) and 2-body integrals mathematically relate to [DFT embeddings](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-nature/issues/26) ?
2. How is [ActiveSpaceTransformer](https://qiskit.org/documentation/nature/stubs/qiskit_nature.second_q.transformers.ActiveSpaceTransformer.html) different from [ECP (Effective Core Potentials)](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-nature/pull/50#issuecomment-781891445) ?
3. If `active_orbitals=None`, how exactly in the code implementation would the active space be chosen around the Fermi level which are the HOMO and LUMO orbitals ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.